# Linq to pick out last item of grouped list

Tags: c#, linq

I will try to explain this.
Say I have multiple items in a list:

```
var products = new List<JObject>();
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Blacks', importance: 200, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Purples', importance: 150, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Yellows', importance: 200, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Oranges', importance: 500, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Blues', importance: 100, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 400, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Greys', importance: 120, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '2' }"));
```

Now I would like to get the last product of each variant in the list.
In this case,it would be:

```
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Purples', importance: 150, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Oranges', importance: 500, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '2' }"));
```

Can this be done with linq?

---

Without like, it can be done like this:

```
var variant = products[0].SelectToken("variant").ToString();
var productList = new List<JObject>();
var count = products.Count - 1;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var product = products[i];
    var nextProduct = products[i + 1];
    var productVariant = nextProduct.SelectToken("variant").ToString();
    if (productVariant.Equals(variant)) continue;
    productList.Add(product);
    variant = productVariant;
}
productList.Add(products.Last());
```

Comment: This would be dead simple if you had actual classes representing your data.

Comment: Agree with @maccettura. Why not use a `Product` class?

Comment: can you show me how to do it with a class? I will just create a generic one

Comment: `GroupBy()` Color, `OrderBy()` variant, then take the `Last()`

Comment: I did it a different way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` the "variant" property and keep the last of each group:

```
var ans = products.GroupBy(p => p.Property("variant").Value).Select(pg => pg.Last()).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

So, because I am using `List<JObject>();` I have to create an AnonymousType and then do my grouping.
I did this:

```
var lastProducts = products
            .Select(m => new
            {
                Colour = m.SelectToken("colour").ToString(),
                Variant = m.SelectToken("variant").ToString(),
                Importance = Convert.ToInt32(m.SelectToken("importance").ToString())
            })
            .GroupBy(m => m.Variant)
            .Select(m => m.Last());
```

Which I believe is the same as my method above.

Comment: Just seems silly not to use a real class, this is just extra, unnecessary work.

Comment: Maybe, but you don't know the context of the test and why I am using a JObect. All products have colour, variant and importance, but they come from a document database and have a miriad of other properties. The only reason they come to my application is for the list to be sorted, the products need to be returned with the same columns but with my sorting in place

Comment: NVM I misunderstood the question.  I thought you wanted the highest variant in each Color

Comment: Why convert from `JObject`?

Answer (score 0):

You can group your `products` by `variant` and then select last item in each group:

```
var products = new List<JObject>();
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Blacks', importance: 200, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Purples', importance: 150, variant: '0' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Yellows', importance: 200, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Oranges', importance: 500, variant: '1' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Blues', importance: 100, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 400, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Greys', importance: 120, variant: '2' }"));
products.Add(JObject.Parse("{ colour: 'Pinks', importance: 100, variant: '2' }"));

var query = from p in products
            group p by p.Property("variant").Value into varGroup
            select varGroup.Last();
```